# Python3 and Python2 installed on cygwin - how do I run pip /w Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, cygwin

Seems like a stupid question but....I can't figure it out.

I can run programs in python2 like so :

```
python run.py
```

I can run programs in python3 with :

```
python3 run.py
```

However

```
pip install pandas
```

will install pandas for Python2.

How do I make it install for Python3?

I have tried -

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py
```

This installs pip, but when I try to install some requirements for a project, I get the error :

```
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Upgrading it using :

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

results in :

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (19.0.3)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as

```
$ ls -1 /usr/bin/pip*
/usr/bin/pip2
/usr/bin/pip2.7
/usr/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/pip3.6
```

you should run

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CMD write:

```
where pip
```

then:

```
where pip3
```

I believe, pip3 which you'll find it's path in your python\sctips\ is what you need to use; it is the Python3 version of pip

So you can try:

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always run pip as a module:

```
python2 -m pip <pip commands here>
python3 -m pip <pip commands here>
python3.6 -m pip <pip commands here>  # same as python3 as of this post
python3.7 -m pip <pip commands here>
```